# Jenkins: Generatin Link to HTML File and Sending It in Email

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job on a Linux server that runs automated testing and generates a results report. Each time the job runs, a new directory is created in the workspace, and the latest HTML results report and all of its needed resources are placed in that directory. The path to the latest HTML test results file will be (from the workspace root): .Expando_BLEG/Results/{newly-created-directory}/Execution_Result.html.

I want to send an email with a link to the latest test results HTML file each time the Jenkins job runs. The link will be in the email's body. What is the way to do this using a Jelly script in the Email-Ext plugin? The Jelly script will have to generate a different link each time the job is run because the latest test results HTML file will be in a different directory each time.

Answer (score 0):

Now i know this is not a direct answer to your question. But i do feel that this can be a good solution to your problem. And this solution will have 2 extra benefits over your proposed solution.

The only prerequisite it has is that you or someone in your team / project is able to change the output directory of the test results.

To make this work, you change the output directory of your test results and other resources to a static folder. At the start of each test run, you make sure this folder is cleaned. Either by a shell command that removes all files, or a SVN / GIT clean that removes all unversioned files.

You can then use the HTML publisher plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin. Use this to publish the HTML with the test results in your Jenkins job by pointing it to your static location. Make sure to check the archive html page in the publishing options. This will make sure the HTML will be stored in that specific build of the job. If you need to archive the other resources, you can do this with the archive artifacts post build step.

Now all the results and resources are cached within that specific build run, and all you need to do is add a link to the run using $BUILD_URL in your mail extension plugin.

As i said, this has two big benefits. First is that all your test resources are hard linked to a specific test run. If you have the results in a separate location, linking them to a specific run will become harder and harder as time goes on.

Second benefit is that your resources will follow the life cycle of that specific run. Your main workspace is usually hard to clean up if you need some items to remain in there. This will probably cause your workspace to grow in size over time. When you have all your resources archived in the job, all the resources will be cleaned up when the build is removed. This can be easily configured in the job configuration.